# Does it need a quotation mark on a noun?

Tags: grammar, quotation-marks

I'd like to know whether it needs quotation marks on weight and length in a sentence like "each physical quantity like weight, length, and so on, can be described by a single number.", such as "each physical quantity like 'weight', 'length', and so on,...".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a quote on weight and length". Maybe you should give the other version you think might be right?

Comment: I would not use quotation marks in this situation because you're referring to the quantities weight, length, etc., not to the words "weight", "length", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in this case, you would not use quotation marks.

Sometimes, quotation marks may be written in a sentence in that way to indicate that the thing in quotes is intended to be seen as a generic idea such as a "fill in the blanks" type of statement.

Comment: It is rather unclear what is meant by 'generic idea such as a "fill in the blanks" type of statement'.